# JavaScript Modal Popup Button closing after Alert Box

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why my alert button on my modal popup is closing my popup after I click on the alert ok button.  Here is my stripped down code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

<! -- language: lang-html -->

<style type="text/css">
#popupBoxTwoPosition{
    top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 120%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display: none;
   
.popupBoxWrapper{
    width: 550px; margin: 50px auto; text-align: left;
    }
.popupBoxContent{
    background-color: #FFF; padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<div id="popupBoxTwoPosition">
    <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
        <div class="popupBoxContent">
            <form runat="server">
                <h3>Popup Box 2</h3>
                <p>You are currently viewing popup box 9.</p>
                    
                <asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" />
                <p>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="myFunction()" />
                </p>
                <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxTwoPosition')" />--%>

                <%--<p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxTwoPosition');">here</a> to close popup box two.</p>--%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxTwoPosition');">here</a> to see popup box two.</p>
</div><!-- wrapper end -->
```

I am not that great at javascript popups - eventually I want to return data from textbox to code behind - any ideas on that as well?  Thanks Pen

Comment: the code format is a crime

Comment: @messerbill Not only the format, also the code by itself.... That must be why nobody is doing asp any more.

Comment: Show HTML, not ASP code.

Comment: I am very sorry that I offended both of you by my code.  I am new to programming and needed help.  I thought this was the place to go to learn without being insulted.  In the time it took both of you to insult me instead you could have take the time to help.  But thank you anyway gentlemen.